# Compare Objects' properties using hashcode

Tags: c#, hashcode, gethashcode, iequatable

I need to know the ways to compare many objects using hashcode. So here is one of the class.

```
public class Test: IEquatable<Test>
{
    public Test()
    {
    }

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public static int SafeGetHashCode<T>(this T value) where T : class
    {
        return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 19;
        hash = hash * 31 + ID.SafeGetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + Name.SafeGetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public override bool isSame(object obj)
    {
         // compare objects here
    }
}
```

But there are 2 errors. Both are same.

'string' does not contain a definition for 'SafeGetHashCode' and no extension method 'SafeGetHashCode' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And for isSame(), I do not know how to write the code. the concept is compare all the objects and if there are 2 same ID & Name, group them together.

```
Item A = new Item();
Item B = new Item();
Item c = new Item();

A.ID = "Exam1";
A.Name = "Apple";

B.ID = "Exam1";
B.Name = "Orange";

C.ID = "Exam1";
C.Name = "Apple";
```

So Item A and C will group together.

Comment: Is your `isSame` meant to be `Equals` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension method must be member of static class, which should take care of first error. Move `SafeGetHashCode` out of your `Test` class so you can use it as extension on `String` and other reference types:

```
public static class TestHashCodeExtension
{
    public static int SafeGetHashCode<T>(this T value) where T : class
    {
        return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

As for implementation of `IEquatable<T>.Equals` (I assume your `isSame` is just incorrectly named method, also strangely marked with `override` - there is no `isSame` in any of .Net classes, especially not in `Object`):

- make sure to implement base `Equals` as well `IEquatable<T>.Equals`
- see sample in [IEquatable.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx)  for implementation of both `Equals` calls

Shortened sample:

```
public bool Equals(Test other) 
{
  return (other == null) ?
     false : (Id == other.Id) && (Name == other.Name);
}

public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
  Test testObj = obj as Test;
  return testObj == null ? false : Equals(testObj);   
}
```

Note: normally `Equals` does not need to use `GetHashCode` first. `Dictionary` (the main reason `GetHashCode` exists) always checks hash code itself before calling `Equals`. In most cases both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` are implemented as per-member hash/comparisons. So unless you know for sure that your class caches result of `GetHashCode` there is no practical reason to check hash-code in `Equals` as you'll end up touching each twice (and `Equals` can short-circuit comparison if first fields are not equal unlike `GetHashCode` that need to use all/most fields to compute result).

Comment: If I do this, I cannot use Test as type arguments.

Comment: @kingjia, if you do what? You need to move SafeGetHashCode outside of your Test class.

Comment: I want to ask. Is hashcode is used to compare objects inside Equals() method??

Comment: @kingjia, normally you don't need to use `GetHashCode` inside `Equals` - see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd just inline it - no need for the extra method:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 19;
    hash = hash * 31 + (ID == null ? 0 : ID.GetHashCode());
    hash = hash * 31 + (Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode());
    return hash;
}
```

Adding unconstrained extension methods pollutes things like intellisense.